# Convert different scientific notations to numeric

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, converters, sql-server-2019

I have a table with a varchar field that contains values with the following structures:

```
1.69665589928627E-06 
3.57807129940753E-07
4.77823428809643E-08
1.58324837684631E-12
1.57160684466362E-13
0.0062
10.1595896112714
0.0505828946151305
0.739
0
```

How to convert these values to `Numeric(12,6)`?

I tried using `CAST`:

```
SELECT CAST (NUM_AREA AS NUMERIC(12,6)) FROM APP

SELECT CAST(CAST(NUM_AREA AS FLOAT) AS NUMERIC(12,6)) FROM APP
```

But the following error is generated:

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
> Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being a `nvarchar`, I suspect you have some bogus data.

Use `try_convert()` which will return a `NULL` rather than throwing a error

**Example or [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/w6EkpwFS)**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([Num_Area] nvarchar(50))  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('1.69665589928627E-06')
,('3.57807129940753E-07')
,('4.77823428809643E-08')
,('1.58324837684631E-12')
,('1.57160684466362E-13')
,('0.0062')
,('10.1595896112714')
,('0.0505828946151305')
,('0.739')
,('0')
,('Not A NUmber')           -- WOULD THROW AN ERROR USING CONVERT or CAST
,('1.57160684466362E-55')   -- REALLY SMALL NUMBER, YOU'LL JUST GET ZERO

 
Select *
      ,try_convert(numeric(12,6),try_convert(float,Num_Area))
 from @YourTable

--**To Identify the Problem Rows**
Select *
 From  @YourTable
 Where try_convert(float,Num_Area) is null
   and Num_Area is not null
```

**Results**

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, I was able to identify the problem thanks to your help. Among millions of records, there were two values with a comma being used as a decimal separator (35,4976865501492 and 0,00454. I adjusted them and it was possible to perform the conversion.